# Azure DataFactory copy data from one database to another, data type issue

Tags: data-migration, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a simple copy data activity in ADF, source is Oracle, sink is postgresql. And the tables between source and sink are identical (table name, column name/type). But when the Oracle column type is Integer/Date/Datetime and the value is null, the job will be failed as following error, it seems the ADF will consider the null value as empty string. When I checking the mapping in the activity, I saw all columns types in Oracle are string (please see the attached image). Anything I can do to fix this issue?

```
'Type=Npgsql.PostgresException,Message=22P02: invalid input syntax for integer: "",Source=Npgsql,'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems use "bulk insert" instead of "Copy command" in Sink setting solve this issue.